# Block Android Notification during night time

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

I am trying to find documentation or a cleaner way of not showing notification (programmatically) during nighttime (sleeping hours). I have a service that periodically checks if certain conditions are met and then I fire the notification. I would want to avoid this when the user is sleeping.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really think you need to.  If the user wants to block notifications, they'll put the device in Do Not Disturb mode which blocks all notification.  I have one set to automatically turn on at night and off in the morning.  Bonus-  when the DND turns off, I get all the notifications I miss.  This is a feature of the Android OS.

If you really wanted to do this-  just check the time before you put up a notification.  If its too late, don't fire it.  Optionally, set an alarm for when you think its late enough, and decide if the user should see them now.

Comment: Thats what I had in mind as well ! But for my use case(time sensitive notification) I am considering checking the users time zone and if it falls in a certain time range I am going to suppress it

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to keep running the program at night without using notifications?
You only need to use WorkManager, JobScheduler or AlarmManager to achieve.